# How to permanently deny accessibility permission? App keeps asking!

Tags: macos, permission, accessibility

Some apps ask for accessibility permission every time they start. It's annoying to have to click "deny" every time.

How can we make this choice permanent?

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't appear to be any way to do this currently. This would have to be something supported by the app. An app can request accessibility permissions whenever it wants.